# Accessing model methods from controller class Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new to Laravel, I am trying things around while going through a tutorial. This is where I am facing an unexpected behaviour.

I have a model `tweet` and a controller named `tweetsController`; when I call `tweet::find()` or any similar method I found this:

> ```
> FatalErrorException in tweetsController.php line 13:
> Class 'App\Http\Controllers\tweet' not found
> ```

I have also tried `App\tweet::find()`.
Everything seems fine through tinker.

Please explain.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
class tweetsController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        $data = tweet::first()->tweetBody;
        return view('tweets.list',['passedData'=> $data]);
    }

    public function delete($id){
        return "here we dele the tweet ".$id;
    }

    public function add(){
        return "i add your tweet to database then show you all the tweets";
    }
}
```

**tweet.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class tweet extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = array(
        'tweetHead',
        'tweetBody'
    );
}

?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few options the maybe generating this error:

- The model/controller namespace is incorrect;
- The name of the file and the class name for the model needs to be "Tweet" with the first letter in uppercase;
- If you set the right namespace on the model "Tweet.php" and import that on your "TweetController.php"

I hope that helps :)

---

UPDATE:

In the TweetController.php add this

```
use App\Tweet;
```

Before the class declaration, like this

```
use App\Tweet;
class tweetsController extends Controller
{
```

And remember to change the controller name in the class declaration like this

```
class TweetsController extends Controller
    {
```

And the controller filename will become "TweetsController.php"

The Model also has to be named "Tweet" and not "tweet" in the class declaration and the filename

```
class tweet extends Model
```

will become

```
class Tweet extends Model
```

and the file will be named "Tweet.php"

and everytime you need to call the model you will do this

```
public function show(){
        $data = App\Tweet::first()->tweetBody;
        return view('tweets.list',['passedData'=> $data]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add** *use Add\User* **below namespace in your controller**